# i want to insert by using subquery from other two tablw but i want to enter fill date column by current date

Tags: mysql, insert

Here's my query:

```
INSERT INTO initial(`name`,`quantity`,`Date`)
select
  c.name AS Item_Name,
  b.Ibyinjiye - i.Ibyasohotse AS Current_Stock_QTY
from product as c
inner join (
  select
    productID,
    ifnull(sum(quantity),0) as Ibyinjiye
  from stockproduct group by productID
) as b on c.productID = b.productID
inner join (
  select productID,
  ifnull(sum(quantity),0) as Ibyasohotse
  from soldstock
  group by productID
) as i on c.productID = i.productID,CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Reformat your code with sql blocks, please. It is not readable.
Maybe add the tag of the database you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Answer (score 0):

The number of columns selected (you have 2) must equal the number of columns being inserted into (you have *3*, not 2).

Use `CURDATE()` to provide a value of today's date for the `date` column:

```sql
INSERT INTO initial(`name`,`quantity`,`Date`)
select
  c.name AS Item_Name,
  b.Ibyinjiye - i.Ibyasohotse AS Current_Stock_QTY,
  CURDATE() -- add CURDATE() to your selected columns
from ...
```